# What stored procedures update a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to query the database somehow to find all stored procedures that update data in a specific table?

I worked on an older system before called Cool Gen which did this exact thing and currently I am wanting something similar.

I'm not interested in stored procedures that use the table (I have that list already, at it is very long).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may have false positives depending on table name (could be in comments or part of a larger object name), or stored procedures that update some other table then reference this one.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id])
  FROM sys.sql_modules
  WHERE LOWER(definition) LIKE '%update%table_name%';
```

I find this a much more reliable "first sweep" than [relying on dependency views](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008).

You may also consider a 3rd party tool like [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/).

Comment: this just returns anything that has the word 'update' and has the table name at any point after the update word...or am i missing something?

Comment: btw, i'm trying out SQL Search by your recommendation.

Comment: That's why I said it's a "first sweep." I'd be very curious to see if anyone comes up with something better that narrows down the list more closely. As my link describes, you can't always rely on the dependency views. You also can't rely on the plan cache because not everything will be there. You also need to consider checking your applications for ad hoc SQL, and you also need to consider any procedures that take the table name dynamically or otherwise construct dynamic SQL. There is no magic "show me all statements that update this table" button - it requires research.

Comment: @AaronBertrand using function to convert multiple spaces to single space will help http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic819042-203-2.aspx Now our Like condition can be, dbo.fn_CleanUp(LOWER(definition)) LIKE '%update table_name%'

Comment: @Pritesh Does it handle carriage returns, and tabs, and embedded comments like `UPDATE /* do the update */ table_name`? No parsing method is going to be perfect, sorry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no it does not :) we need hell lot of regular expresiion and string pattern matching to get exact result. Not sure T-SQL has big enough librarary to achieve this sofasticatelly, may be SQLCLR is ths way to go here....

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) from sys.sql_modules 
             where definition like '%UPDATE <table_name>%'
```

Comment: I think this is missing the table name. Also on a case-sensitive server it won't catch `Update` or `update`. Finally, please use the `{}` button to highlight code samples.

Comment: It also won't catch any dynamic SQL, but that's really hard to find.